# CSS Animation when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using AJAX to load pages on my site.

Whilst a page is loading - I want the logo to spin in order to signify that it's loading.

The jQuery (Not sure if it's actually javascript, I'm new to java/jquery) being used to control the css when the page is loading is

```
function loadPage(url)
{
url=url.replace('#page','');

$('#logo').css('display','none;');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page='+url,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
            $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            $('#logo').css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }
```

The CSS controlling the animation is

```
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }



    @-moz-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    #logoholder { 

    }

    #logo   { 
        background: url(images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 

        width: 130px; 
        height: 130px; 
        -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms; /* 40 seconds */
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -moz-animation-name: spin; 
        -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms; /* 40 seconds */
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

        -ms-animation-name: spin; 
        -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms; /* 40 seconds */
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
        -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

        /* boooo opera */
        -o-transition: rotate(3600deg); /* works */
    }
```

Is there a property that I can add to the CSS (via jquery) so that the logo doesn't spin when the page isn't loading... At the moment the logo spins constantly

Maybe there is a property that I can take away from the "#logo" selector, which will invalidate the spin

and then I can add a certain property whilst the page is loading (through javascript) to make the spin work?

thanks

Comment: you hide logo before while loading, and you show the logo why finished loading

Comment: Java != JavaScript ; jQuery == JavaScript (actually a Library build in JavaScript :)

Comment: So how would I edit the original code to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding the CSS animation to `#logo`, bind it to a class - e.g. `.spin`. When Ajax is starting, add the `spin` class to `#logo`, using `addClass`:

```
$("#logo").addClass("spin");
```

When ajax content finished loading, use `removeClass`:

```
$("#logo").removeClass("spin");
```

This way you can easily show the logo normally, and make it spin only when ajax is acitve.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `<body class="loading">` in your page.

Then on the bottom of the page, have `$('body').removeClass('loading');`

Then target your css animation with `body.loading #logo` selector.

Once the page is fully loaded, the jquery will remove the .loading class and the animation stops.

Also in your `$.ajax` you should add the `.loading` class at `beforeSend` and remove the class on `complete` event.

Comment: @Roy I'm on a mobile and needed to browse off the page to doublecheck the $.ajax details, thus I submitted an incomplete answer and came back to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hiding the logo initially, and showing after the content loads(as mentioned in the comments).  Also, you are using the `display` property to hide it, and the `visibility` property to hide it.  Those are not the same.  I switched your functions below, and use the `display` property for both.  Not sure if there are other errors, but give this a try, it should get you in the right direction.

```
function loadPage(url)
    {
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#logo').css('display','block');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
              {  
               $('#pageContent').html(msg);
               $('#logo').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
```